# codebird array showing tweets using api

Tags: php, arrays, api, twitter

OK, I am using [codebird](https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php) to read and write tweets using php. It's a twitter account that is protected so I need to use the API to display the tweets on our private network. I am able to make tweets without a problem, it's retrieving our own tweets I'm struggling with.

```
$reply = (array) $cb->statuses_homeTimeline();
print_r($reply);
```

this gives the output of (this is just the first one in the array)

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [created_at] => Thu Feb 06 09:08:43 +0000 2014 [id] => 431353751824134144 [id_str] => 431353751824134144 [text] => test 3 [source] => web [truncated] => [in_reply_to_status_id] => [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [user] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2292936619 [id_str] => 2292936619 [name] => JPress Support [screen_name] => JPressSupport [location] => [description] => This is an automated account letting you know of any issues. Any tweets made to the account will not be seen. Thanks, Johnston Press IT. [url] => [entities] => stdClass Object ( [description] => stdClass Object ( [urls] => Array ( ) ) ) [protected] => 1 [followers_count] => 1 [friends_count] => 0 [listed_count] => 0 [created_at] => Wed Jan 15 16:11:20 +0000 2014 [favourites_count] => 0 [utc_offset] => 0 [time_zone] => Casablanca [geo_enabled] => [verified] => [statuses_count] => 3 [lang] => en-gb [contributors_enabled] => [is_translator] => [is_translation_enabled] => [profile_background_color] => C0DEED [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [profile_background_tile] => [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/423490507906359297/t-ECTyZW_normal.png [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/423490507906359297/t-ECTyZW_normal.png [profile_link_color] => 0084B4 [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6 [profile_text_color] => 333333 [profile_use_background_image] => 1 [default_profile] => 1 [default_profile_image] => [following] => [follow_request_sent] => [notifications] => ) [geo] => [coordinates] => [place] => [contributors] => [retweet_count] => 0 [favorite_count] => 0 [entities] => stdClass Object ( [hashtags] => Array ( ) [symbols] => Array ( ) [urls] => Array ( ) [user_mentions] => Array ( ) ) [favorited] => [retweeted] => [lang] => et )
```

However, if I do something like

```
<? echo $reply[0]; ?>
```

it gives no output. I'm guessing it's something simple, but I can't work it out, please can anyone help, I'm just needing the bit at `[text] =>`

Comment: Please use next time `print_r` to get a formatted output of array and post it. Single line array is hard to read.

Comment: That was from print_r, that's why I struggled, it didn't do any formatting and I've never seen these objects before

Comment: But you didn't copy it from the source code view?

Comment: No, I copied it from the output in Chrome, what do you mean by source code view?

Comment: If you are using `print_r` there are whitespaces for indentation. The normal *view* doesn't show them. Press [CTRL] + [U] to open the source code view of your page.

Answer (score 0):

sorted it!

```
$tweet1 = $reply[0]->text;
```